# How to apply indexing in mongodb to read the whole data at once faster

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

As the data retrieving is too slow when I am querying for the whole data at once in MongoDB using the query `db.find({}, {'_id':0})`.
I am using PyMongo
How can I retrieve all the documents faster using Python driver.
I think indexing can make data retrieve faster but how to apply Indexing on whole collection to make `db.find({})` query for whole collection runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing will drastically speed up finding **subsets** of documents within a collection, but will not (to my knowledge) speed up pulling the entire collection.

The reason indexing speeds up finding subsets is that mongo does not have to iterate through each document to see if they match the query- instead mongo can just go to each specific document location by looking it up in the index.

If you are returning the entire collection- then the index has no effect. Mongo fundamentally has to iterate through every document in the collection.

The storage engine you chose *will* effect hte speed, so I suggest you read up on the differences between Wired Tiger and mmapV1. I know there are third party ones but can't think of them off the top of my head.